# Is an uncountable infinity necessarily "bigger" than a countable infinity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I'm not conversant in cardinality theory or set theory to formulate my question in much of a meaningful sense but I'll give it a try in hope of finding the right way to ask the question as an answer.

So, from Cantor's diagonal demonstration as well as from intuition, I'd assume that an uncountable infinity is "bigger" than a countable infinity in some sense if a framework for such comparison can exist. However, in physics, we often encounter situations in which we have the same Hilbert space spanned by two different sets of eigen bases, one of which comprises of uncountably many eigen vectors and the other of countably many. For example, the Hilbert space of a particle on a ring can be either spanned by the eigen vectors of the (angular) position operator $\phi$ or by the eigen vectors of the angular momentum operator $\partial_{\phi}$. The former set has uncountably many eigen vectors (I presume so because the eigen values are $[0,2\pi)$) whereas the latter has countably many eigen vectors (because the eigen values are integers).

Since both the sets of eigen bases span the same Hilbert space, I can't shake the intuition that none of the sets can be "bigger" than another. But this runs in contradiction with my general expectation that an uncountable infinity should be somehow "bigger" than a countable infinity.

I have a strong feeling that this confusion has to do with the sloppy way in which I'm using Hilbert spaces but I'd appreciate some help in understanding what I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: In physics they say a lot of peculiar things.... are these "eigen vectors of the (angular) position operator" really elements of the Hilbert space?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Meh, they provide a complete basis. They're essentially delta functions so they're more like density of states in Hilbert space than states themselves. But I thought that would not be important because they nonetheless provide a complete basis. And one can express each position eigenstate in terms of angular momentum eigenstates and vice versa.

Comment: Mathematical jargon is often enough misleading and certainly carries (probably intentional) shock-value to non-mathematicians. The theorem we read as saying the cardinality of the real numbers is 'bigger' than the cardinality of the natural numbers is true in the model in question because that model doesn't include all the functions we're talk about when we say there's a bijection between any two countably infinite sets.

Comment: Wikipedia has nice pages on Hilbert space. In particular, you might want to consider the difference between an orthogonal basis and a Hamel basis. An orthogonal basis for a Hilbert space may be countable, but a Hamel basis must be uncountable. A Hamel basis allows elements of the space to be written as an infinite sum of the basis elements. I haven't looked at this stuff in over thirty years, so don't accept my comments at face value. However, I have indicated a place to start looking.

Comment: So does a Hilbert space like $L^2[0,1]$ have "delta functions" as elements? I'm sure you know the answer.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thanks! Yes, of course, the delta functions are not *in* the Hilbert space. And that's the point I suppose that only normalizable combinations of these delta functions are in the Hilbert space and the Hilbert space doesn't capture the full content of all that can be constructed out of delta functions, e.g., a delta function itself. Thanks for the clarifying comment! :)

Comment: @ChrisLeary Thanks, sounds interesting, I will look it up. :)

Comment: @Chris: Hamel basis does *not* allow for infinite sums.

Comment: To your specific example of the angular position operator vs angular momentum operator, if you're not already familiar, you might find it interesting to research spectral measures and expansion in bases of generalized eigenvectors/eigenfunctions.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila - I think I misspoke. I meant infinite (norm) convergent sums, as in the standard Hamel basis for the space of null sequences $c_0.$

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Wow! Thirty or so years does a number on your memory. I meant Schauder basis, not Hamel basis.

Comment: @Dvij Mankad - Please see my rely to Asaf. I meant Schauder basis, not Hamel basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the group $\Bbb Z$ is generated by $\langle 1\rangle$, but also by $\langle\Bbb Z\rangle$. So from your point of view, an infinite set seems to be the same size as a singleton.

Set theory *is* the framework for comparing infinite sets, and in the standard context of $\sf ZFC$, uncountable implies, and in fact synonymous with, "larger than countable".

You are forgetting that the process of "spanning" here is such that the cardinality can grow larger, also because it involves taking infinite sums.